# Dynamic rewrites in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on some rewrites and redirects in my htaccess file. My reason for doing this is because I am developing a new design and layout for an existing website therefore I need to redirect to keep hold of the Google rankings etc.

So the old (existing) URL looks like this:

```
/news/internet-shopper-numbers-continue-to-grow-$21378232.htm
```

and the new URL will look like this:

```
/industry-news/small-business-website-design/internet-shopper-numbers-continue-to-grow/800715788
```

In the old URL `internet-shopper-numbers-continue-to-grow` is dynamically generated, where as in the new URL `small-business-website-design`, `internet-shopper-numbers-continue-to-grow`, and `800715788` are all dynamically generated.

So my issue is how do I get from 1 URL to another if only 1 of the dynamically generated variables is available.

I was thinking perhaps it would be a good idea to do a PHP redirect instead where I can get the data from the URL process through database to get all data needed to generate the new URL, but I'm not sure if this is good practice, this would also mean having to match the old URL file directory which is not the current case.

I'm guessing I start with something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /news/%{QUERY_STRING}(.)(\\d+)(.)(htm)$
RewriteRule ^industry-news/(.+)/%1/(\d{9})
```

I know this is very basic and kinda wrong but I'm working on this for the first time and I'm stumped.

-- extra question --

am I able to do something like this?

```
RewriteCond /new/%{QUERY_STRING}(.)(\\d+).htm$
RewriteRule ^industry-new/article/article.php?direct=%1
```

I dont know how to go about testing these really, but would that work?

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: Thanks, i've give this a read, I only came to here because I have been through so many tutorials and not found what im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely a good idea to do all redirection stuff in php. Just have a simple "catch-all" .htaccess

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  .* index.php
```

then transform urls as you want in php and send a location header when necessary. It might be a good idea to add 301 status code for "old" urls.

Comment: I will make them 301 for sure, just trying to get my head round the main code right now, so could I perhaps still take the %{QUERY_STRING} to the index file, pull it out and then use as a variable for the database?