# combining multiple htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic rewrites in htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281778/dynamic-rewrites-in-htaccess-file)

I am currently tackling a rather harsh redirect which is driving me crazy.

I am looking to get from this url:

```
/news/give-your-blog-the-google-treatment-$21378233.htm
```

to this:

```
/industry-news/small-business-online-marketing/give-your-blog-the-google-treatment/800717101
```

where `give-your-blog-the-google-treatment` is generated from a databse in both urls and where `small-business-online-marketing` and `800717101` are generated from the database for the new url.

So therefore the only way to get to the second url is get some data out of my database before the redirect is performed. So im figuring that I need to do some kind of redirect from:

```
/news/give-your-blog-the-google-treatment-$21378233.htm
```

to something like:

```
/redirect/index.php?name=give-your-blog-the-google-treatment
```

where I can then do `$_GET['name']` and get the details out of the database and finally do a PHP 301 redirect to get to the url I want something like:

```
/industry-news/$cat/$name/$id
```

So I think I pretty much have the theory behind it sorted, but the actual coding I have no clue, and how to test if it works... again in stumped. If anyone could help that would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: [Didn't you already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281778/dynamic-rewrites-in-htaccess-file)? What's wrong with the old one?

Comment: @DaveRandom - My apologies I felt this was a much better worded answer and could see a way of adding extra questions to the old post.